# Google Chrome doesn't launch in the Debian VM

Tags: linux, google-chrome, debian

I installed the Google Chrome in the `Debian 8 VM` with Parallels in MacBook Pro. The installation is successful and I can see the Google Chrome App among the other Apps. I believe this a permission issue but can be something different as I'm very new to Linux.

I downloaded the `google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb` file and run the command to install,

```
$ sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

I removed the Chrome 2-3 times with the commands and re-installed,

```
$ apt-get remove --purge google-chrome-stable 

$ apt-get remove --purge google-chrome-stable

$ apt-get autoremove

$ apt-get -f install
```

These doesn't help to resolve the issue.

When I run in the sources list,

```
$ sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list

### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

The main sources list is,

```
$ sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8 _Jessie_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary #20150425-14:07]/ jessie main

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8 _Jessie_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary #20150425-14:07]/ jessie main

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main

deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
```

The direct run from the terminal produces the outputs like,

```
$ google-chrome

[22266:22311:1230/124137.020697:FATAL:nss_util.cc(631)] NSS_VersionCheck("3.26") failed. NSS >= 3.26 is required. Please upgrade to the latest NSS, and if you still get this error, contact your distribution maintainer.
Aborted

$ google-chrome-stable 

[22377:22418:1230/124142.875056:FATAL:nss_util.cc(631)] NSS_VersionCheck("3.26") failed. NSS >= 3.26 is required. Please upgrade to the latest NSS, and if you still get this error, contact your distribution maintainer.
Aborted
```

The `locate` command returns output like,

```
$ locate google-chrome-stable

/home/chaklader/Downloads/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
/usr/share/doc/google-chrome-stable
/usr/share/doc/google-chrome-stable/changelog.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/google-chrome-stable.1.gz
/var/cache/apt/archives/google-chrome-stable_63.0.3239.108-1_amd64.deb
/var/lib/dpkg/info/google-chrome-stable.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/google-chrome-stable.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/google-chrome-stable.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/google-chrome-stable.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/google-chrome-stable.prerm
```

How to solve the issue and launch the `Google Chrome`?

Comment: How did you install it? What do you see if you run `google-chrome` in a terminal?

Comment: @IvanKozik Sorry for the late reply. I updated the question, please, kindly show the way out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the error messages, we see the string:

```
NSS_VersionCheck("3.26") failed. NSS >= 3.26 is required.
```

So it probably means that you don't have the correct version of NSS installed.

To update, if you are using a modern version of Debian (such as Debian 8), issue the commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libnss3
```

If you are using an older version of Debian, and you're not willing to upgrade, you will have to find a way to install a later version of libnss3 yourself. It is possible that you may be able to use the packages from the most recent version of Debian, but this is not guaranteed to work, and you may be better off trying to compile from source.

Comment: Wow! this works like magic. Would you mind to elaborate your answer about how do you come to this solution? I mean this works, but, I have no clue why THIS SOLUTION WORKS for me.

Comment: I've updated the question to try to provide a more detailed answer.